# attribute Error with ImportLib in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to dynamically import a particular module and method . To import the module dynamically, I have written CheckCode.py which has a class SystemConfigure and method Snp_Configure. The module which needs to be imported is SnpBase.py which in turn has class SnpBase and method Unix_Base_Configure. To import the module and method dynamically, I am using importlib functionality. However I am getting the AttributeError when doing the same. Can some one please help me in figuring out what is missing. Thanks.

**CheckCode.py**

```
class SystemConfigure():

    def __init__(self,snp_dict):
        print ("I am in Init of the SystemConfigure")
        SystemConfigure.Snp_Configure(self,snp_dict)

    def Snp_Configure(self,snp_dict):
        dict = snp_dict
        osname = dict['osname']
        protocol = dict['protocol']
        module = "Snp" + protocol
        func_string = module + "." +osname + "_" + protocol + "_" + "Configure"
        #func_string = osname + "_" + protocol + "_" + "Configure"
        print ("You have called the Class:", module, "and the function:", func_string)
       # my_method =getattr(import_module(module),"SnpBase.Unix_Base_Configure")
        mod = import_module(module)
        #return mod.SnpBase.Unix_Base_Configure(snp_dict)
        func = getattr(mod, func_string)
        func(snp_dict)
```

**SnpBase.py**

```
class SnpBase():

    def __init__(self,dict):
        pass
        print("BASE INIT")

    def Unix_Base_Configure(self,dict):
        print ("GOT IN THE UNIX BASE CLASS FUNCTION")

    def Linux_Base_Configure(self,dict):
        print("GOT IN THE LINUX BASE CLASS FUNCTION")
```

**Error Message**

```
  func = getattr(mod, func_string)
AttributeError: module 'SnpBase' has no attribute 'SnpBase.Unix_Base_Configure'
```

Comment: I am using the following statement 
from importlib import import_module

I am also calling the CheckCode with the following command.
m = SystemConfigure({'protocol':'Base','osname':'Unix','device':'dut'})

Answer (score 0):

Module `SnpBase` does not have a function called `Unix_Base_Configure`.

Module `SnpBase` has a class called `SnpBase` and that class has a function called `Unix_Base_Configure`

so the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'SnpBase' has no attribute 'SnpBase.Unix_Base_Configure'
```

is correct.